# What are some introductory texts on the teachings of Mutazilites?

Tags: islamic-philosophy, books, mutazilites

I'd like to do some reading on the teachings of Mutazilites.

What are some good, introductory texts on this topic?

Comment: What would you call an introductory text? And about which language are you talking. Else one of the most known and used books of a Mu'tazili scholar is the tafssir of az-Zamakhsahrai called al-Kashaf in which there certainly Mu'tazili views are represented.

Comment: Well say type of text for someone who knows the core principles of islam but not very familiar with islamic sciences such as fiqh (and no arabic).